# Can't Install ubuntu on HP Pavilion X360 Convertable (2019)

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb

I tried a couple of ways to install Ubuntu on my computer, but I can't even open the installer. First, it has given me an ACPI error and now it's just saying that it's unable to find a medium containing a live file system.
I checked the md5 sum sha256 of the iso that I downloaded.
Methods that i tried was disable the:

-I made the acpi=strict

-I made the acpi=off

-Tried using safe graphics

-My computer does not contain any operating system right now (deleted windows)
-Tried different usb port

I am using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) to create a bootable USB. I tried it on different computers and it worked perfect.

My computer specs are

- i7 8565U,
- 16GB samsung RAM,
- 512GB WDC SSD,
- 2GB Nvidia MX250,
- Realtek WiFi and Bluetooth combo card

What can I do to install Ubuntu on this system?

Comment: "Everything"? If we're going to be able to help, we need specifically to know exactly what you tried and exactly what the results and error messages were. Please click [edit] to add those to your original question.